# Suppress dot when printing status of a service with systemctl

Tags: systemd

How do I suppress the dot that gets printed to the left of the service name when I run `systemctl status XXX`? I'd like to save the output of this command to a bash variable and print it. The presence of the dot in the output causes my script to fail, most probably because the dot is a unicode char.

```
# systemctl status network
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-10-11 09:16:29 PDT; 6h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Oct 11 09:16:24 172.100.139.200 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Oct 11 09:16:24 172.100.139.200 network[1376]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Oct 11 09:16:28 172.100.139.200 network[1376]: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Oct 11 09:16:29 172.100.139.200 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
```

Comment: Perhaps `systemctl status network | tr -d '●'`?

Comment: This might be the solution I am seeking. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the problem you're trying to solve is to avoid Unicode characters as part of the output, then you can call the systemd command with a locale setting that does not use UTF-8, in which case systemd will print a `*` instead of the dot.

You can temporarily set a non UTF-8 locale to a single command by setting the `LC_CTYPE` variable to something like `C` or `POSIX`.

For example:

```
# LC_CTYPE=C systemctl status network
* network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-10-11 09:16:29 PDT; 6h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Oct 11 09:16:24 172.100.139.200 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Oct 11 09:16:24 172.100.139.200 network[1376]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Oct 11 09:16:28 172.100.139.200 network[1376]: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Oct 11 09:16:29 172.100.139.200 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
```

Comment: Excellent. Just the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2):

See `man systemctl`:

> status
>
> This function is intended to generate human-readable output. If you
>   are looking for computer-parsable output, use `show` instead.
>   ...
>
> show
>
> To select specific properties to show, use `--property=`. This command is intended to be used whenever computer-parsable output is required.

Comment: I looked at the `show` option and it isn't in a format that I like/want. I'd like to get the same output as `systemctl status xxx` emits, but without the annoying dot.

Comment: @linuxfan sure, what would Lennart know about parsing text anyway...

Comment: I'm not questioning Lennart's knowledge of text parsing. Doug has provided a satisfactory answer to my question.